# Second Borel Cantelli extension

Tags: probability-theory

I'm thinking about an extension of the lemma. If we have a sequence of events, with even terms independent but odd terms dependent, and the other conditions hold. Can we still say the probability of ${E_{n},i.o.}$ is $1$?

Comment: What about specifying other dependences (e.g. between odd and even terms)? It is worth looking at the [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma#Proof_2) of the second lemma; it uses mutual independence at the step $P(\cap_{n\geq N} E_n^c)=\Pi_{n\geq N} P(E_n^c)$ and uses the fact the RHS is zero. Under a general dependence structure, the probability of the intersection of $E_n^c$ may be greater than the product of their probabilities, and then this proof collapses.

Comment: If you check out the wiki link, they also mention a counterpart where they replace the independence assumption by monotone increasing sets for large indices.

Comment: However, we can think of a subsequence of even terms and the probability=1. And the original sequence contains this subsequence so the probability must be greater or equal to 1. Then it should be 1. What is the flaw here?

Comment: I mean the sequence ${E_{2n}}$ has probability 1, and it is a subsequence of ${E_{n}}$

Comment: Oh, I see your point. Yea, that makes sense to me. So more generally, for any subsequence $E_{n_k}$ satisfying the hypotheses of the second lemma, the probability of $E_n$ i.o. is one.

Comment: By the same token when $E_n$ satisfies the hypothesis of the first lemma, the probability of any subsequence $E_{n_k}$ i.o. is zero.